# Dot notation after SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, query

I'm troubleshooting a test class that I didn't write, and I don't know who wrote it.

What exactly is this code doing?

```
Integer.valueOf([SELECT Potential_Lives__c FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1].Potential_Lives__c)
```

I know it's getting an integer value from a SOQL statement. But that dot notation after the SOQL, what is it doing? IT seems redundant.

Comment: its takes field Potential_Lives__c from object Opportunity

Comment: ^ From `Opportunity`

Comment: ^ to continue to add on:  `LIMIT 1` denotes that only 1 opp record will be returned, regardless of how many there are in the system. Because only one Opp is returned, it makes sense to use the dot notation to reference a specific field from that opp. If more than one opp were returned by the SQL statement then this would give an error.

Comment: They must be using `SeeAllData=true`. If you ever do find out who wrote it, do us all a favor and kick them in the shins.

Comment: @AdrianLarson they're not using SeeAllData=true. Could that be why I"m experiencing errors?

Comment: It's just a pretty weird decision to query for the `Potential_Lives__c` value instead of just using one they decided on. Like just use `42` instead of the code you asked about. It's hard to know what sort of boundary values make the most sense without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The . (dot) notation after the SOQL is a field reference (dereference??).

i.e.

```
system.debug([Select ID, Name From Account Where ID = 'xxxxx'].Name);
```

it is similar to:

```
Account a = [Select ID, Name From Account];
system.debug(a.name);
```

The downside to doing it as you have shown is you lose the ability to check for no records returned, empty list, etc so you increase the fragility of your code. It is typical not a good idea to do.

Although you may have an ID to use in the query you have no guarantee that the ID used in the code exists so this is typically a better pattern:

```
Account[] a = [Select ID, Name From Account Where ID = 'xxxxx'];

if(a.isEmpty()){
   //Do something as nothing was found
}else{
   //We have an account so do something with it
}
```

The above is longer but provides the most flexability. I would guess you could use the original . (dot) notation if you already queried and you know the ID will result in a returned record